# Как назначить выполнение задачи на определенное время?

Tags: node.js, datetime

Всем привет. Пытаюсь написать на node скрипт, который будет работать 27/7. 
Мне нужно выполнять первую функцию в 22-00, вторую в 6-00. Это я с помощью setTimeout сделал. Проблема в запуске. Я не могу понять, как мне узнать, какую из функций запустить в данный момент и какое время она должна работать. 
Т.е. первая функция работает с 22-00 до 6-00, вторая наоборот. Теоретически мне нужно просто понять, какой в данный момент промежуток времени. Возможно, я буду запускать скрипт кроном раз в минуту.

Comment: (new Date()).getHours();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Узнай текущее время и в соответствии с ним запускай ту или иную функцию.